# Format DateTime short date to long date in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

How can I change the date format in Flutter? I want to swap the positions of date and month.

```
    // prints 2022-09-08 13:46:45.778709
    print('old date');
    print(date);

    // prints September 8, 2022
    print('new date');
    print(DateFormat.yMMMMd('en_US').format(date));
    
    // how to print in 8 September, 2022?
    print('new format');
```

Comment: your initial date time is string or DateTime?

Comment: It's actually string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl/install) package and do this:

```
    DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        .parse('2022-09-08 13:46:45.778709');
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy').format(tempDate);
    print('formattedDate = $formattedDate'); // 08 September, 2022
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I show "8 September, 2022".

Comment: I updated my answer. check it out.

Comment: @HassanYousuf is it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

The following code converts `08/09/2022 15:55` to `09/08/2022 11:55 PM`

```
var inputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
var inputDate = inputFormat.parse('08/09/2022 15:55'); // <-- dd/MM 24H format
print(inputDate);

var outputFormat = DateFormat('dd MMMM, yyyy');
var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
print(outputDate);
```

Comment: Thank you.  But I need to print long date like this "8 September, 2022". I need to show date first

Comment: I update my answer.... first you need to convert `String` into `DateTime`.. then you convert the `DateFormat`